# C# - Laying out form as in Java's Swing

Tags: c#, java, winforms, layout-manager

I'd like to start programming in C# (I've studied it a little in the past and I know it has many similarities with Java).

But what I LOVE in Java is the ability to lay out components with code. I seriously dislike form designers, and as far as I know, Visual Studio does not give you that condition.

I'd like to know if C# has Layout Managers or something alike, for that would fit a lot better in my likes.

TIA, André

Comment: If you go with WPF, you can use XAML for laying out your UI. I'm not sure about winforms but they might be XAML based too.

Comment: @xbonez, winforms isn't xaml based at all... It was here long before the WPF (with its XAML) came to being...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what user interface technology you use.

Both WPF/Xaml and Windows Forms can be done entirely in code, though it's a bit trickier with WPF, as it's really oriented for use with Xaml.

With Windows Forms, the designer actually builds the code required (see form.designer.cs), so you can see exactly what it would take to write this "by hand".

For WPF, it's a bit trickier, but still possible.  [Charles Petzold's WPF book](http://www.charlespetzold.com/wpf/) actually takes this approach, and starts with a code-first approach to building WPF user interfaces, then later shows how to use markup (xaml).  That being said, the Xaml approach is far nicer, and more flexible in many ways than doing everything in code.

Comment: Thank's, I guess I'll check that book. Maybe sticking with XAML is not a bad idea, for I also plan on developing for Windows 8 later on.

Comment: @AndréLeria XAML is really nice once you get used to it.  I don't use the designer - I hand write xaml most of the time, so it "feels" like writing code, but you get all of the ease of use and flexibility.  That being said, I actually wouldn't recommend that book if you're just learning - learning XAML from a code-first approach is just painful.  (I just pointed it out because it's the only one I know of that does it that way)

Comment: I really like handwriting the code and Layouts, that's what kept me from using Visual Studio for a long time. Having all the code written by my keyboard feels more 'safe' than having it 'written' by some dragging-and-dropping. And XAML is not bad at all, since I'm used to XML and stuff.

Comment: @AndréLeria I'd look at WPF/Silverlight with XAML, then.  You can write it all with keyboard - no drag and drop required (you can even just turn the designers off - have it open in the XML editor by default, though the preview is handy ;) )

Answer (score 2):

There are ways to get it to behave similar to Java In winforms

- [DevExpress](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraLayoutLayoutControltopic) has a Layout manager
- [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14635/Drop-dead-easy-layout-management) has a article on one you can use
- There is also [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty26a068.aspx) on different ways .Net Handles Layouts
- Here is a [tutorial](http://zetcode.com/gui/csharpqyoto/layoutmanagement/) on Layouts
- there is also different [panel layouts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754152.aspx)

WPF has several different layout managers see [Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514628%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

No one is forcing you to use a designer, you can hard-code everything from scratch. Not sure who told you that you can't do this with Visual Studio, but I would stop listening to that guy.

Answer (score 1):

In the background the codes for the layout are generated for you. You can check the code in the myfile.designer.cs file

The image below shows some layout in visual studio:

- Left: the layout controls
- right: example of FlowLayout like you have in Java

[image]

Looking at the code you have these generated for the flowlayout. So you can do other controls like that and learn how it's being generated

```
       this.flowLayoutPanel1 = new System.Windows.Forms.FlowLayoutPanel();
        this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.button2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.button3 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.button4 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.flowLayoutPanel1.SuspendLayout();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // flowLayoutPanel1
        // 
        this.flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.button1);
        this.flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.button2);
        this.flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.button3);
        this.flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.button4);
        this.flowLayoutPanel1.FlowDirection = System.Windows.Forms.FlowDirection.LeftToRight;
        //Other directions: BottomUp, RightToLeft, TopDown

        this.flowLayoutPanel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 42);
        this.flowLayoutPanel1.Name = "flowLayoutPanel1";
        this.flowLayoutPanel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 71);
        this.flowLayoutPanel1.TabIndex = 0;
```

But designer will save your time.

Answer (score 0):

check out System.Windows.Forms for non web stuff

also System.drawing and system.text may be interesting but most of the UI stuff is in system.windows.forms.